# is it possible to redirecturl without changing url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I'm creating a chrome extension that if you *domain.com*, it will redirect you to *domain.com.ipaddress.com*

Here's the main code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {
    var url = details.url.split("/")[2];
    var url = "http://" + url + ".ipaddress.com";
    return { redirectUrl: url };
}, {
    urls: ['*://*/*']
}, ['blocking']);
```

My problem is how do i display the contents of *domain.ipaddress.com* without the changing the url (*domain.com*). Because when i visit *google.com* the url text changes to *google.com.ipaddress.com*

I know i'm bad at explaining. To understand more, im gonna express what i want using an image.
[image]

Comment: I believe you cannot do so. The user **must** acknowledge what domain they're currently on. This is risky for payments gates and online banking. This is possible with proxy and/or VPN.

Comment: @AdamAzad Yeah, i found a fiddler (web debugger) which modifies headers, request, response and others.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, that's not possible.

You can't influence the address bar, it will show the actual source of the page / final redirected address.

As noted in comments, to permit otherwise would be a severe security problem.